# How to ovveride an imported method by my own

Tags: python

I have a python file which can be resumed as follow :

```
from external_libs import save

class FakeClass1(MotherFakeClass1):

    @property
    def field(self):
        if self.settings['save_parameter_booelan']:#settings come from the mother class but irelevant
             import FakeClass2.save as save
             # I want to override the save method by the one defined in the FakeClass2
             return BehaviorModifierField(super(FakClass1, self).field) #The behavior Modifier decorate the new field but it's irelevant of what it does.
         return super(FakClass1, self).field


    def fakeMethod(self, boolean_val):
        save('blabla')

class FakeClass2:
     @staticmethod
     def save(test):
         #irrelevant core of the method
```

The idea is here but I struggle to find the right to do this.
I think I could do it more properly if I could move the `FakeClass2` in another file but I don't want to.
Do you have a better idea ?

Comment: `if save_parameter_boolean: FakeClass2.save(some_input)`: is that what you want?

Comment: `FakeClass1` should simply take the function to be called as an argument, not a boolean value instructing `field` to use a different function.

Comment: yeah but I don't want to use if because in the real code, i use the save method at a lot of places and putting if everywhere is uselessly verbose.

Comment: @chepner no I don't want that,

Comment: @BobReynolds Any reason why not?

Comment: @chepner because I don't want to add the save method as part of my object, it has no purpose here. The use of a different save should be more transparent to the FakeClass1.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `field` method? Only to override `save`? And if `save` is not overrided (`save_parameter_boolean = False`) what should happen when you call the `save` method?

Comment: @Valentino my example isn't explicit enough, I will update it.

Comment: What is the point of `save_parameter_boolean` if `field` uses `self.settings['save_parameter_boolean']`? Your example is getting more and more convoluted the more you try to explain what you want. You appear to have some serious class design problems.

Comment: No point, I just forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

A `staticmethod` is not the right choice, as its invoked via `Class.method`. Your save is not used like that. And even if it were, it's on `FakeClass`, *not* `FakeClass2`.

If you want to invoke a different `save` depending on the class, just add a `save` METHOD (not function!) and use the function of choice. E.g.

```
from library import standard_save

class A:
     def work(self):
         self.save()

     def save(self):
         standard_save()


 class B(A):

     def save(self):
         do_something_else()
```

Comment: The save isn't linked to the class, the save function is used elsewhere in the project by other object independently from these object implementation. Therefor i don't want it to be method. It's more of a util function, like a quicksort or any algo function.

Comment: I understand that. Do you understand my example? If you want to change the behaviour of an object, you need to override methods. That's (for some definition of only) the only way to go. Inside these overridden methods you are free to do whatever you need to do, e.g. invoke a util function.

Comment: But the save method isn't in the FakeClass1 in the first place, it's an util method that I want to mock.

Comment: What stops you from putting it there?

Comment: It's in another package that contains all the util methods. It does not belong in this class as a method.

Comment: I'm not talking about the package with util methods. Do you have control over the class-definitions?

Comment: Over fakeClass1 one and 2 yes, (but I don't have control on where FakeClass1 is instancied) but not on the MotherFakeClass1

Comment: In your example, you define a method on FakeClass1 (over which you claim you have control, and which supposedly is to decide what to do). If that's the case, my solution works.

Comment: yes but I don't want it because I will have to change save('blabla') by self.save('blabla') everywher in my code.

Comment: Well, then that's your choice. If you can make that choice, you can find a better solution ;)

Comment: That is why I want to override the import of the external_libs save by the one in the FakeClass2.

Comment: Yes, and that's not possible. Period. I showed you a way that works. You decided to not follow that due to other self-imposed constraints. Then I'm out of ideas, and you either find a way yourself, or have to accept that your problem can't be solved within those self-imposed constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass a boolean; pass the function to be used.

```
import external_libs

class FakeClass1:
    def __init__(self, save_function=external_libs.save):
        self.save = save_function

    # Does this method do anything other than change the save function
    # to use? If not, it can be eliminated.
    def field(self):
        # Use self.save as the function to save things

    def fakeMethod(self, boolean_val):
        self.save('blabla')

class FakeClass2:
     @staticmethod
     def save(test):
         #irrelevant core of the method

instance1 = FakeClass1(FakeClass2.save)
instance2 = FakeClass1()  # Default of external_libs.save
```

Comment: I editied my post, there is no ReadOnlyExtractAPI in my example. sorry

Comment: Adjusted; I might be confused about which function you want by default, though.

Comment: by default I want the save from the external_lib, and depending of how I run the code I want the one from the FakeClass2. Your example could resovle my problem but I don't want to change the constructor of my class.

Comment: Why not? Having some boolean value that just delays the choice of function to use isn't a great design. Be explicit: if you want to use a different save function, say what it is up front instead of burying the change inside another method.

Comment: Because in the real code, the field that determine how I will run my code is in a big dict containing other informations. Plus I can't change the part of the code that instanciate the FakeClass1, so I only know which save I want only at the moment I'm running this code. My example isn't explicit enough I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things.

Having a boolean value determining the behaviour of the `save` method means that the `save` method behaves differently depending on the instance of the class, according to the boolean value of the instance.
If this is what you want, this is the simplest way I can think.

```
class FakeClass1(MotherFakeClass1):
    def __init__(self):
        #your __init__ here

    def save(self):
        if self.settings['save_parameter_booelan']:
             FakeClass2.save()
             #or whatwever method you want to use in this case,
             #even if is not this class method or another class method
        else:
             raise NotImplementedError
             #or whatever code should be executed by save
             #when save_parameter_boolean is false
```

Comment: I removed the boolean in the constructor.

Comment: Using `self.settings` from a parent class does not change the concept. Let me edit my answer

Comment: but the save method isn't in the FakeClass1 in the first place. I don't want FakeClass1 to have a fake method, he doesn't have too.

Comment: Then we are not talking about overriding. Do you just want `field` method behaving as another function?

Comment: yes I need that but the main subject is the save method.

Comment: It is about overriding because I would like to override the import of the save function in external_libs by the one in FakeClass2.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to redefine the behaviour of a function without touching the code of that function? I think is not possible. `override` does not work that way. You ovveride the behaviour of the class method you are defining (same name of parent class, but different behaviour), you cannot redefine the parent class itself through overriding, or by any other way as far as I know.

Comment: I know for sure it is possible to override the import of a method by another import because python will just interpret the import in order and erase the precedents import. Also it's not a parent, the save method is not in another class, and the FakeClass1 does not inherit from it. It's an imported function from another file.